# On click width of div is changed

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website. 
I have a specific `div` that's supposed to be sticked to the right side of the content div and I have noticed a very strange problem.

When you click on one of the links in the `div` the width of the `div` will be changed and get wider. Why does it do that?

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="login">

        <form method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Welcome Test Test<br />Click <a href='#'>here</a> for admin.!</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>You are logged.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">Edit your details.</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2j1g200g/

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser shows the problem that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing **float:right** from the main div or from the login class seems to fix the problem.

Was there a reason behind using it on both or was it by accident?

Comment: Ok cool, thought you were trying to do some weird fancy thing! lol

Answer (score 0):

change #login padding from 5% to 5px

Comment: I think it fixed it, why did it do it though?

Comment: No idea why, looks like happens only with chrome.